# Javafx Scene switching causing stage size increase

Tags: java, javafx, scene, stage, sizing

I am using Javafx (without using FXML), and I am passing the stage into the a controller to change the scene on the stage when a button is clicked. The scene changes correctly but the size of the stage and the scene increases.It increases in size by about 0.1 (in the width) and the height sometimes also increases (not every time).

Here is the controller being used.

```
 public class Controller {

 public Controller(){

}
 public static void homeButtonhandler(Stage stage){
        stage.close();

     }
 public static void adminButtonhandler(Stage stage){




     adminPane adminPane1 = new adminPane(stage);

    Scene adminScene = new Scene (adminPane1);

     stage.setScene(adminScene);
    }}
```

The adminPane extends another class I created called mainPane which both extend the Pane class. Which have other panes within them to create the GUI structure. The sizing for the main pane is set up like so:

```
    top = createTop(stage);

    this.getChildren().addAll(top);
    this.setWidth(stage.getWidth());
    this.setPrefWidth(stage.getWidth());
    this.setMaxWidth(stage.getWidth());
    this.setMinWidth(stage.getWidth());

    this.setHeight(stage.getHeight());
    this.setMaxHeight(stage.getHeight());
    this.setMinHeight(stage.getHeight());
    this.setPrefHeight(stage.getHeight());
```

I am testing the classes using:

```
public class test extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    //primaryStage.setResizable(true);

    mainPane myPane = new mainPane(primaryStage);
    Scene homeScene = new Scene (myPane);

    primaryStage.setScene(homeScene);
    primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/icons/joulesIcon.png")));
    primaryStage.show();


    }


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}
I believe it has something to do with my passing of the stage, any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: Create a new Stage.

Comment: If I create a new stage the window closes and reopen for a moment. Which is not the streamlined desgin I'm going for.

Comment: My guess is that a component does not fit within the Stage original dimensions. I think this causes the stage to grow to fit the new components.

Comment: I thought this might be the case, but the new scene is the same as the previous one just I have changed the colour of the background (so I can tell them apart).

Comment: Replace the root of the existing scene instead of replacing the scene.

Comment: Just saw this on a different question. http://www.javafxtutorials.com/tutorials/switching-to-different-screens-in-javafx-and-fxml/

Comment: How would I replace the root ?

Comment: To replace the root => `scene.setRoot(newNode)`

Answer (score 2):

I also found that stuff was being drawn below the bottom of the window when I used `primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, primaryStage.getWidth(), primaryStage.getHeight()))`. My case was resolved by using the dimensions of the old scene rather than the dimensions of the primary stage.

```
public void setScene(Parent root) {
    Scene oldScene = primaryStage.getScene();
    primaryStage.setScene(oldScene == null
            ? new Scene(root, primaryStage.getMinWidth(), primaryStage.getMinHeight())
            : new Scene(root, oldScene.getWidth(), oldScene.getHeight()));
}
```